# Missing the Rails gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.4 rails`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to fix [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951337/cannot-send-e-mail-with-rails-2-3-4i-could-with-2-3-2) and I ended up with a new one.

I have installed ruby 1.8.6, but using Built-in JRuby 1.4.0 for my app.

Everything was working fine until I updated every gem(as specified by the answer I got from that link) and everything crashed: ever since I tried to start the app I received the following error message:

> Missing the Rails 2.3.4 gem. Please
>   `gem install -v=2.3.4 rails`, update
>   your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in
>   config/environment.rb for the Rails
>   version you do have installed, or
>   comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use
>   the latest version installed.

Then, I tried to uninstall the updates(to v2.3.8, most of them), so the last version is 2.3.4.

In my config/environment.rb file I have this:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.4' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

so I guess everything is as I left it before the update.

The question is....why do I keep getting the error and I can't start the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got this working by changing the gem path for my Built-in Jruby 1.4.0 platform, pointing to the gems' directory of Ruby, instead of NetBeans(as it was before).

I hope it works well in the future.

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into rvm if you are running multiple ruby/gem environments. It takes maybe half an hour to read up on, download, and configure, but it makes life way simpler.