# Which must be the gems directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some weeks ago I upgraded my NetBeans version from 6.7 to 6.8.

Yesterday, while trying to solve some issue, I updated the gems' versions and suddenly the app stop working, throwing me the error message:

> Missing the Rails 2.3.4 gem. Please
>   gem install -v=2.3.4 rails, update
>   your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in
>   config/environment.rb for the Rails
>   version you do have installed, or
>   comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use
>   the latest version installed.

Rails 2.3.4 is installed, and its specified correctly in environment.rb file as follows:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.4' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

I spent hours trying to fix this, when I discovered I had gems both in my NetBeans directory and in the Ruby directory. So I changed the Gems Home to the Ruby directory(instead of the NetBeans dir) and the app magically started.

That being said, I think that's not the proper solution, because I'm using both directories and I guess it's bringing me problems. Fox example, I cannot send emails any more, as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951337/cannot-send-e-mail-with-rails-2-3-4i-could-with-2-3-2).

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not keep gems in one place?

From your other post i'm assuming you're using windows so if you're not using pik (like rvm but for windows) then i don't see the point of 2 (or more) gem locations as it's obviously leading to problems.

I'm sticking with 1 gem location.

Comment: I'm too. I didn't know why I had those two directories with gems. Anyway, now I just put all of them together in one folder and it's working ok.